# How to align a toString

Tags: java, formatting, alignment, tostring

I have a list of name that also have the sex and the the amount of people who have that name.

Ex:

Isabella F 22822

Jacob M 22011

Sophia F 20566

Ethan M 17956

Emma F 17277

I want to center align the sex and right align the count like this:

Isabella______F_____22822

Jacob_______M_____22011

Sophia______F________205

Ethan_______M______7956

Emma_______F____ 17277

When I try to format it Compiles whenI try to run it but get an java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException error.

```
public String toString()
{
        return String.format("%.30s%1.15c%7.d", Name, Sex, Count);

}
```

Comment: Are 'Name', 'Sex' and 'Count' String variables? If so, they definitely should be lowercase.

Comment: IMO it's not a good idea to do formatting in toString(). Your formatting is specific to your current purposes, so you do need a method to output your String in the specified format. But your class will be more reusable if that method is not toString

Comment: What exactly you want to achive? Post minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Below code not tested - coded here on the page, its a possible fairly simple but manual way to do it :

```
public String spc(int n)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++) sb.append(" ");
   return sb.toString();
}

public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(name).append(spc(20 - name.length()));
    sb.append(sex); 
    sb.append(spc(20 - count.length())).append(count);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**name** is left aligned on 20 spaces, **sex** not aligned, **count** aligned right. Of course you can still format the values using String.format(), you'll also see that I've changed the case of the variables **name**, **sex** and **count**. I also assume that they are already strings.